# Expected number of trials until first success, probability of each trial being a success varies

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We have a random variable $P$ which takes on continuous values between $0$ and $1.$  The pmf of $P,$ denoted $f_P,$ is continuous but otherwise arbitrary.

We have an experiment where we begin by taking a random sample of $P,$ then asking the question, is this value less than a uniformly chosen random number in $[0,1]?$  If so, the experiment is over.  If not, we repeat the trial -- sample $P,$ see if it is less than a uniformly chosen random number in $[0,1].$

What is the expected number of trials until the experiment ends?  If $P$ always  took the same value, we would just call it the probability of success for any given trial, and then the geometric pmf would provide all the information needed.  However, the fact that $P$ changes after every trial is what has me thrown off...  Just been thinking about probability some these days :)

Looking for any intuitive explanations, suggestions, or calculations. Thanks in advance!  And pardon me if I am not using my probability theory notation/definitions correctly, its been awhile.

Comment: This is still just geometric.  Given the distribution for $P$  and the joint distribution for $P$ and $X$ (your uniform variable) let $\psi=Prob(P<X)$).  then your problem refers to the geometric distribution with probability $\psi$.

Comment: Would it follow then that the mean number of trials would be $\frac{1}{\langle Prob(P < X) \rangle}?$  I guess I am not too sure how to extract any information out of the fact that its geometric, but $\psi$ varies each trial.

Comment: $\psi $ does not vary each trial!  Each trial has exactly the same probability of success (unless I have misunderstood, which is always possible).

Comment: Just to be clear:  I imagine that your process is simply that you have two random variables $Y,Z$ and you independently sample them at each trial.  A success is when $Y<Z$.  That will have some probability $\psi$ and each trial will have the same success probability.

Comment: Hmm, I think I see why $\psi$ should be constant.  So If I had a joint probability distribution for $P$ and $X,$ then $Prob(P < X)$ just means integrate over all the values of $P$ and $X$ where $P < X?$

Comment: Yes.  And I'm guessing that you mean for $P,X$ to be independent so the joint distribution is just the product distribution.  Of course, that isn't essential.

Comment: Yup you are correct about $P$ and $X.$ Thanks for all the helpful comments!